# expo run:android --variant release

Tags: expo

Running: `expo run:android --variant release`.

Getting the following error:

```
 Package "expo-camera" does not contain a valid config plugin.
 Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#creating-a-plugin.

 Unexpected token 'export'.
```

In my app.json, I added the following:

```
"plugins": [
  "expo-camera",
  "expo-av",
  "expo-location",
  "expo-file-system",
  "expo-constants"
],
```